# Why does built-in sum behave wrongly after "from numpy import *"?

Tags: python, numpy, integer, long-integer

I have some code like:

```
import math, csv, sys, re, time, datetime, pickle, os, gzip
from numpy import *

x = [1, 2, 3, ... ]
y = sum(x)
```

The sum of the actual values in `x` is 2165496761, which is larger than the limit of 32bit integer. The reported `y` value is `-2129470535`, implying integer overflow.

Why did this happen? I thought the built-in `sum` was supposed to use Python's arbitrary-size integers?

---

<sub>See [How to restore a builtin that I overwrote by accident?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152760) if you've accidentally done something like this at the REPL (interpreter prompt).</sub>

Comment: Python can handle arbitrarily large numbers; what is your code?

Comment: x=[1,2,....] is a long list of integer numbers, add up to 2165496761.

Comment: Yet another reason to not use `import *`...

Comment: @notilas No, `import *` was the reason! You got bit by it once, now never do it again.

Comment: Note that 64-bit builds of Python will require a 64-bit integer overflow to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you get this invalid value is that you're using `np.sum` on a `int32`. Nothing prevents you from **not** using a `np.int32` but a `np.int64` or `np.int128` `dtype` to represent your data. You could for example just use

```
x.view(np.int64).sum()
```

On a side note, please make sure that you **never** use `from numpy import *`. It's a terrible practice and a habit you must get rid of as soon as possible. When you use the `from ... import *`, you might be overwriting some Python built-ins which makes it very difficult to debug. Typical example, your overwriting of functions like `sum` or `max`...

Comment: I assume the issue here might apply in other areas, such as reduce(mul,[1,2,3,4,5...] ) ? How might this be fixed in problems doing products on large lists?

Answer (score 14):

Doing `from numpy import *` causes the built-in `sum` function to be replaced with `numpy.sum`:

```
>>> sum(xrange(10**7))
49999995000000L
>>> from numpy import sum
>>> sum(xrange(10**7)) # assuming a 32-bit platform
-2014260032
```

To verify that `numpy.sum` is in use, try to check the `type` of the result:

```
>>> sum([721832253, 721832254, 721832254])
-2129470535
>>> type(sum([721832253, 721832254, 721832254]))
<type 'numpy.int32'>
```

To avoid this problem, don't use star import.

If you must use `numpy.sum` and want an arbitrary-sized integer result, specify a `dtype` for the result like so:

```
>>> sum([721832253, 721832254, 721832254],dtype=object)
2165496761L
```

or refer to the builtin `sum` explicitly (possibly giving it a more convenient binding):

```
>>> __builtins__.sum([721832253, 721832254, 721832254])
2165496761L
```

Answer (score 1):

Python handles large numbers with arbitrary precision:

```
>>> sum([721832253, 721832254, 721832254])
2165496761
```

Just sum them up!

To make sure you don't use `numpy.sum`, try `__builtins__.sum()` instead.

Comment: mine returns -2129470535. Windows 64 machine

Comment: @notilas: Then your `x` is not what you expected it to be. Python integer support is platform independent.

Comment: I have copied and pasted your text to my machine. "sum([721832253, 721832254, 721832254])", it returns a negative value.