# How to restore a builtin that I overwrote by accident?

Tags: python, built-in

I accidentally overwrote `set` by using it as a variable name in an interactive python session - is there any way that I can get access to the original `set` function without just restarting my session?

(I have so much stuff in that session that I'd rather not have to do that, although of course I can if necessary.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get back an overridden python built-in function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885760/how-to-get-back-an-overridden-python-built-in-function)

Comment: @Ta946 It does, but my question was asked before that one and already has an answer, so I'm not sure why that's relevant?

Comment: i flagged the questions as duplicates. i guess that auto-generated my comment?  wasn't expecting any activity on a 9yo question

Comment: Ah, makes sense! I'm occasionally still around on various stackexchange sites so it gives me activity notifications, it's not like I was checking this specifically XD

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Just delete the name that is masking the builtin:

```
>>> set = 'oops'
>>> set
'oops'
>>> del set
>>> set
<type 'set'>
```

You can always still access the original built-in through the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)  module ([`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) on Python 2, with underscores and no `s`); use this if you want to override the built-in but want to defer to the original still from the override:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.set
<type 'set'>
```

If you have trouble locating where the masking name is defined, do check all namespaces from your current one up to the built-ins; see [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-scoping-rules) for what scopes may apply to your current situation.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html):

```
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.set
<class 'set'>
```

---

For Python 2, you can use [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html):

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.set
<type 'set'>
```

or simply(no imports required):

```
>>> __builtins__.set
<type 'set'>
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html):

> **CPython implementation detail**: Users should not touch `__builtins__`; it
> is strictly an implementation detail. Users wanting to override values
> in the `builtins` namespace should import the `__builtin__` (no ‘s’)
> module and modify its attributes appropriately.

Comment: Well and what do I do if the method `builtins.open` was changed?

Comment: @TomášZato Then it's not possible to get it back as far as I know. If your application requires doing something like this then you should keep a reference intact to such variables.

Answer (score 0):

To use builtin wrapper, first assign its **original address** in a variable like `X`

After your work is done then set it to `None` and set back the original address to builtin function.

Example

1. ```
   X = __builtin__.isinstance
   ```
2. ```
   __builtin__.isinstance = myisinstance
   ```
3. work is done

   ```
   __builtin__.isinstance = None
   __builtin__.isinstance = X
   ```

Comment: From a suggested edit: "WARNING: it is previous work. Preserve before you lose the builtin  in the text of the code!"

Comment: Why set it to `None`? I don't see any reason to do that if you're just going to immediately override it again.