# Reloading method that has been overwritten

Tags: python, matplotlib, methods, figure

I have overwritten `plt.figure = <some random text>`, and now I cannot use the `plt.figure` method as normal.  How do I reload the `.figure` method from `matplotlib.pyplot` again so I can use it?

I tried `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` but `plt.figure` is still equals to the text I defined as by accident.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore a builtin that I overwrote by accident?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152760/how-to-restore-a-builtin-that-i-overwrote-by-accident)

Comment: @G.Anderson no, that technique will not work for an attribute of a non-builtin global.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused by your question and why you can not just restart and not overwrite that variable. However, importlib can probably help you out:

```
import numpy as np
import importlib
np.array = 1
print(np.array) # 1
importlib.reload(np)
print(np.array) # <built-in function array>
```

Comment: that's brilliant, thanks!  certainly a re-load of the terminal also works, but I have other data which takes some time to load and this is helpful as it allows me to re-load a method in a package if somehow i've stuffed it up by overwriting it.