# Why do I get "TypeError: open() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)" or "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)" when opening a file?

Tags: python, file-io, python-os, shadowing

**If your question was closed as a duplicate of this, it is because** you have code along the lines of:

```
from os import *

with open('example.txt', mode='r') as f:
    print('successfully opened example.txt')
```

This causes an error message that says `TypeError: open() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)`.

Alternately, you may have tried specifying the `mode` as a positional argument instead of a keyword argument, like:

```
from os import *

with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    print('successfully opened example.txt')
```

But that does not work either - it gives a different error, which says `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`.

You may have noticed that there is no such keyword argument `flags` for the built-in `open` function:

```
>>> help(open)
Help on built-in function open in module io:

open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
    Open file and return a stream.  Raise OSError upon failure.
```

Indeed, if you try removing `from os import *` from the code example, you should find that the problem is resolved.

This question is an artificial canonical duplicate, to explain what happened, i.e.: **Why is it different when the code says `from os import *`**? Also, how can the problem be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Using a star import like `from os import *` - or explicitly using `from os import open`, or perhaps taking some more indirect route - means that the name `open` will no longer refer to the built-in `open` function (which is also available from the `io` standard library module), but instead to `os.open`.<sup>1</sup>

[This function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) is also used for opening files, but it provides a lower-level interface. It offers more options for controlling how the file is opened.

In particular: the `flags` argument here is analogous to the `mode` used by the built-in `open`, but it offers many more options (most of which are platform-specific). Rather than a string, it should be an integer produced by bitwise-OR of some flag values (i.e., it directly reflects a C interface). The `mode` argument, on the other hand, indicates the (UNIX-like file system) permissions that will be used when creating a new file, if `open` should create one.

Again: **normal code should not use this, but instead use the built-in `open`**. (To fix the file permissions after creating a new file, use `os.chmod`.)

To avoid this name collision, simply don't use star-imports and don't import `open` explicitly. Instead, if `os` standard library module functionality is needed, just `import os` and then use qualified names.

At the interpreter prompt, [`del open` will get rid of the *global* binding of the name `open`, making the *builtin* one visible again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152760). Alternately, since the built-in `open` is the same function as the built-in `open` (not simply another function doing the same thing, but literally the same object), we can re-import that name: `from io import open`. These techniques *would* also work within a script that did `from os import *` *after* that import, but it will be much cleaner and less error-prone in the long run to just avoid star-imports.

<sup>1</sup> Keep in mind that a name can only refer to one thing at a time. See also: [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978) and [Why does code like `str = str(...)` cause a TypeError, but only the second time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605).