# Range is not callable? in python, typeError

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, range, typeerror

'I'm having problem with same code on different Jupyter notebook,
one note runs the code with out any error
in one it throws an error -->TypeError: 'range' object is not callable

Output i got with a notebook:
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

In other notebook:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 2 list_1 = list(range_1)

TypeError: 'range' object is not callable'

Can anyone help me out with this?

```
range_1 = range(10,20)
list_1 = list(range_1)
print(list_1)
```

Comment: I guess you re-assigned `list = some_range_object` somewhere, and after that the `list` is no longer callable. Here is another thread on how to restore the original: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152760/how-to-restore-a-builtin-that-i-overwrote-by-accident)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is the difference between the two notebooks?

Comment: I guess in jupyter new file is called as notebook, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: are you sure you aren't calling the range function anywhere else in the notebook that's failing?

Comment: I have used range function in the same notebook but did not call it , but here i have used different variable for this range (different range that what i used earlier) and wanted to print that as list,
here i have uploaded my notebook

https://github.com/SandeepKaruna/Python/blob/main/Extra%20Assignment%20Level%20-1%20%26%202%20%28Python%29.ipynb